# shading view is different than render view

Tags: rendering, shaders, viewlayers

hello community I am much worried while adding material to the objects in blender 2.8. 
I am facing problem that the shading view show the accurate colors what I do made as shown in figure below. [image]

as it shows a good metalic color but when I goes to the render view or render the image weather in cycle or in evee shows different results like the premade metal color in shading view looking like this in render view as shown below [image]

please sort out the problem I shall be very thank full to you.

I am also attaching the .blend file 
[image]

Comment: probably the same as this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153161/objects-rendering-well-in-shading-but-not-in-layout/153268#153268

Comment: no it is not same I have added the outdoor background world picture still it is not working please check out the file and tell how to make a perfect metalic outlook in the cycle

Comment: I confirm, this is the same, after I've downloaded your file.

Comment: can you please make the metal color and resend me file so that I can check out the mistake please

Comment: The world texture needs to be surface/background, then as color, choose environment texture and for instance forest.exr. This file may not work as the texture depend on your environment, but here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6605" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6605/)

Comment: yes boss you are great its done.  I am very thank ful to you for you patience and describing the problem efficiently. stay blessed.